# I created an animated coin in GIMP but it does not clear after each frame

Tags: animation, gif, gimp

I am not sure if my title explains it right, but here is the image, and you can see what's wrong.

[animation http://askibadev.comule.com/animation.gif](http://askibadev.comule.com/animation.gif)

The individual layers in GIMP do not show this error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer... pay attention when saving the GIF for the "Frame disposal" option in the GIF dialog.